# Publish message in Saga where type is known only runtime

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit

I want to publish a message from a Saga where the messgae type is not known compile time, only runtime. So far i've only found methods for publishing a message with generic signature - i cannot find any where i can publish a runtime type.

I'm in the works of modifying the Sample-Batch application https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Batch to be able to batch any message type

How Sample-Batch is configured

```cs
Initially(
    When(BatchJobReceived)
        .Then(context => Touch(context.Saga, context.Message.Timestamp))
        .Then(context => SetReceiveTimestamp(context.Saga, context.Message.Timestamp))
        .Then(Initialize)
        .PublishAsync(context => context.Init<ProcessBatchJob>(new
        {
            BatchJobId = context.Saga.CorrelationId,
            InVar.Timestamp,
            context.Saga.BatchId,
            context.Saga.OrderId,
            context.Saga.Action
        }))
        .TransitionTo(Received));
```

What i want to accomplish

1. Receive the `BatchJobReceived` message
2. Deserialize the inner message Json using `InnerMessageAsString` and `InnerMessageType`
3. Store the inner message on the state
4. Publish the inner message
   And then keep state of the messages when they return

```cs
Initially(
    When(BatchJobReceived)
        .Then(context => Touch(context.Saga, context.Message.Timestamp))
        .Then(context => SetReceiveTimestamp(context.Saga, context.Message.Timestamp))
        .Then(Initialize)
        .Then(context => DeserializeInnerMessage(context.Saga, context.Message))
        .PublishAsync(context => context.Init(context.Saga.InnerMessage, context.Saga.InnerMessageType))
        .TransitionTo(Received));
```

```cs
static void DeserializeInnerMessage(BatchJobState state, BatchJobReceived job)
{
    var innerMessageType = Type.GetType(job.InnerMessageType);
    var innerMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(job.InnerMessageAsString, innerMessageType);

    state.InnerMessage = innerMessage;
}
```

There are however no `context.Init()` methods taking a Type parameter, it solely have a generic signature `context.Init<>()`.

How do i accomplish this? Or any other approaches more suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one, you can use your own `ThenAsync` statement to publish an unknown type as `object`:

```cs
.ThenAsync(x => x.Publish(x.Saga.InnerMessage, x.Saga.InnerMessageType)
```

Comment: So simple, if you know where to look. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Appreciated.

Comment: I want to send a per-batch specified message type once complete. Since it's an interface i cannot create an instance by the type name and im not allowed to send an anonymous object along with the interface type.

var batchDoneMsgType = Type.GetType(context.Saga.BatchDoneMessageTypeAsString);
var batchDoneMsg = new { message.BatchId };

await context.Publish(batchDoneMsg, batchDoneMsgType);

But i get an "System.ArgumentException: Unexpected message type: <>f__AnonymousType6<System.Guid>"